# Is this script only written in javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't own this script but i'm curious to know if its written in anything besides javascript and html.

Is there certain place to write scripts like this? If so, could you recommend any websites? Thanks so much.

```html
<script>
  function login() {
    var username = $('#loginusername').val();
    var password = $('#loginpassword').val();
    document.getElementById("logindiv").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loginimage").style.display = "inline";
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("logindiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("loginimage").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("logindiv").style.display = "inline";
        if (xmlhttp.responseText.search("Redirecting") != -1) {
          setInterval(function() {
            window.location = "index.php"
          }, 3000);
        }
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax/login.php?type=login", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
  }
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Chither.com The best Slither and Agar.io bots service</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
  <meta name="Description" content="free bots, best experience, without lags, Slither.io bots - Best Bots for Slither, agar.io bots - Best Bots for agar.io" />
  <meta name="Author" content="" />
  <meta name="Reply-To" content="" />
  <meta name="Robots" content="all" />
  <meta name="Rating" content="general" />
  <meta name="Keywords" content="Slither.io, chither, Slither bot, Slitherbots, Slither bots, Slitherio bots, Chither.com, hacks, cheats, free, bots, Slitheriobots, Slitherio bots, Slither.io bots, Bot, Worms, Worm, Bots, Worms, support, best, lagfree, Slither, agar.io, agar bot, agarbots, agar bots, agario bots, hacks, cheats, free, bots, agariobots, agario bots, agar.io bots, Bot, Minion, Bots, Minions, support, best, lagfree, agar, mass bot"
  />
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Toastr style -->
  <link href="css/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Gritter -->
  <link href="js/plugins/gritter/jquery.gritter.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Mainly scripts -->
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/mcustomscrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/actions.js"></script>

  <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
  <script src="js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Flot -->
  <script src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
  <script src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js"></script>
  <script src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
  <!-- Peity -->
  <script src="js/plugins/peity/jquery.peity.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/demo/peity-demo.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
  <script src="js/inspinia.js"></script>
  <script src="js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery UI -->
  <script src="js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- GITTER -->
  <script src="js/plugins/gritter/jquery.gritter.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Sparkline -->
  <script src="js/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Sparkline demo data  -->
  <script src="js/demo/sparkline-demo.js"></script>
  <!-- ChartJS-->
  <script src="js/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
      i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
      i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
      }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
      a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
      a.async = 1;
      a.src = g;
      m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-77344643-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.cookieconsent_options = {
      "message": "This website uses cookies to ensure you get the best experience on our website",
      "dismiss": "Got it!",
      "learnMore": "More info",
      "link": "",
      "theme": "dark-bottom"
    };
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/1.0.10/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Toastr -->
  <!--<script src="js/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body class="gray-bg">
  <!--<body style="background-image: url(http://slither.io/s/bg45.jpg); background-repeat: repeat;">-->
  <div class="middle-box text-center loginscreen animated fadeInDown">
    <div>
      <div>

        <!--<h1 class="logo-name">CHITHER.COM</h1>-->
        <img src="logo.png" />

      </div>
      <!--<h3>Welcome to Chither.com</h3>-->
      <p>Login in</p>
      <div class="m-t">
        <div id="logindiv" style="display:none"></div>
        <img id="loginimage" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" style="display:none" />
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="username" id="loginusername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" name="password" id="loginpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left">
          <a href="http://chither.com/tos.php">By logging in, you agree to our ToS</a>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <button class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" type="button" onclick="login()">Sign in</button>

        <!--<a href="#"><small>Forgot password?</small></a>-->
        <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Do not have an account?</small></p>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" onClick="location.href='register.php'">Create an account</button>
      </div>
      <p class="m-t"> <small>© All Rights Reserved Chither.com 2017</small> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Mainly scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#signinForm").validate({
      rules: {
        login: "required",
        password: "required"
      },
      messages: {
        firstname: "Please enter your login",
        lastname: "Please enter your password"
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A place to write these? That's a... text editor. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes. It is also using a javascript library called jQuery and a ton of plugins but at the end of the day they are all just javascript. It also includes some CSS files too. (And as c0dekid pointed on there is some server side stuff going on too since it is using Ajax and referencing php files.)

Comment: `JavaScript`, some core `JavaScript` and javascript with ajax request

Comment: If you mean the scripts that are getting called in ajax? Then yes, they used PHP to handle the ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this "script" is written in only HTML and Javascript, but it uses multiple plugins and frameworks. This is defined by the link href and script tags. For example bootstrap is an front-end(how your page looks) framework and Jquery is an Javascript framework.

It does refer to other files for example PHP(e.g. index.php) and CSS styles(E.g. in link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"). Without these CSS files your site will not have the same appearance and functionality.

The most simple way to write HTML is in notepad and safe them as .html. You can then open them with you preferred browser. For starting tutorials I would recommend W3Schools. For example a tutorial on Js is: https://www.w3schools.com/js/ or html: https://www.w3schools.com/html/